# How to print out the variables of a redirected query string?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a basic redirection set up:

```
function example_add_rewrite_rules() {
  $made_year = '(\d{4})?';
  $make = '([a-z]{1,20})';
  $model = '(.+)';
  add_rewrite_rule( 'c/'.$made_year.'/?'.$make.'/'.$model.'/?$', 'index.php?page_id=46&made_year=$matches[1]&make=$matches[2]&model=$matches[3]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'example_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

My hope is that whenever the user hits the page with a URL of ../c/2015/ford/f150, that URL is stored in a query string.

So, hopefully, the user will see this: "/c/2015/ford/f150"

While I see this: "?page_id=46&year=2015&make=ford&model=f150"

I cant tell if its working or not though. If I type in /c/2015/ford/f150 it will redirect me to the correct page/page_id. But I cant figure out for the life of me how to print those query variables to the page so I can at least see that the query string is configured correctly and has variables stored in year, make, and model.

Summary: Have I done anything wrong in the code above? If not, how do I print the query string variables to the page?

Aside: I'm jumping into an ocean of PHP and I'm still trying to learn how to swim. If I misstated something, forgive and correct me, for I know not what I do.

Comment: `print_r($_GET)` or `var_dump($_GET)` not working for you?

Comment: Nope. It returns array(0) { }. That's one of the parts I don't know about either. I've seen a few instances during my research that $_GET doesn't work in this scenario. So I don't know if the array I want is actually empty or if $_GET just isn't working. @CD001

Comment: Are you `POST`'ing your data? `method="post"`, or have a controller to handle the url?

Comment: What you see there is what I have in my functions.php. That's all of it. I am using the data from the query string to pre-populate some forms on my page.the user will search for a car on Google, and the ad URL will store that information. So when they click on the ad, the forms on our page will pre-pop with the info searched on Google. What do you mean by `POST`'ing my data? What is a controller, and what would it do for me? Again, please forgive my ignorance, this is all a large stretch for me. @Tim Hallman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use your own query vars within rewrite rules, you need to add them to the list of known vars:

```
function wpd_query_vars( $qvars ) {
  $qvars[] = 'my_year';
  $qvars[] = 'make';
  $qvars[] = 'model';
  return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_query_vars' , 10, 1 );
```

Then you can output their values in the template with get_query_var:

```
echo get_query_var( 'model' );
```